# What is the difference between kernel release and kernel version in linux?

Tags: linux

I went through [this](https://linuxize.com/post/uname-command-in-linux/) article that explains the command 'uname -a'. The command shows Kernel Release and Kernel version along with some other info. What is the difference between Kernel Release and Kernel Version?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184055/what-if-any-is-the-difference-between-a-software-release-and-a-version answer your question?

Comment: @KamilCuk, so the linux OS comes with 2 kernels?

Comment: No. We humans like to call stuff using words, not numbers. So we have "Citroen C5" (Release) and Citroen C5 has multiple "versions" - 1, 2, 3 generations of the model. It's similar in software. It's a convention we humans use to differentiate stuff.

Comment: @Anurag, your system can have many kernels installed at the same time. I currently have 4, but only one (the newest, by default, on my distro) is used.